# animate owl carousel slide to move from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate, owl-carousel

We can make the slide to go from right to left in Owl carousel using the following:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
});
```

Is there a way to make the slide go from bottom to top?

Answer (score 0):

A vertical mode is not supported in Owl Carousel.
You'll have to dig into the code yourself or build further on already customized versions.

Another option would be to use another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can use animation peoperty

$('#testimonial-slide').owlCarousel({
        animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
        animateIn: 'slideInUp',
)};